# Check deep down object inside ngIf statement

Tags: angular

I have following structure of data inside `module` object

```
{
    "date": "2018-01-19T14:06:57.588Z",
    "id": "lpybtKeZpr7lPDZMQtcO",
    "moduleNum": 1,
    "name": "New Module For AMD",
    "published": true,
    "qNums": 10,
    "attendies": [
      {
        "date": "2018-01-22T06:06:46.990Z",
        "points": 5,
        "retry": true, // <-- here it is
        "retryAttempt": 0,
        "uid": "som6XQYufyWrHW6SJvRfWM6iCGg1"
      }
    ]
}
```

Now i can't figure out how to show a button according to the value of `retry` which is nested inside my `module` object.

i tired many ways, but failed

```
<button *ngIf="module.attendies?.retry" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm manage-button" (click)="attendTest(attendTestModal,module)">Retry Test</button>
```

Comment: `attendies` is an array not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access via index because `attendies` is an *array*.

```
module.attendies[0]?.retry
```

Comment: it throws me error `Parser Error: Conditional expression module.attendies?[0]?.retry requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression`

Comment: Try this `module.attendies[0]?.retry`

Comment: error again `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`,

Comment: Means that your `attendies` is undefined. I will give you the property access path, the errors try to resolve yourself - `module.attendies[0].retry`

Answer (score 1):

For button :

```
<button *ngIf="module.attendies[0]?.retry" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm manage-button" (click)="attendTest(attendTestModal,module)">Retry Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`*ngIF`** in this case  and attendies is an array. so access using index

```
<span *ngIf="module.attendies && module.attendies.lengh" >
<h1> {{module.attendies[0].retry}}</h1>
</span>
```